# Uploading images - Google App Engine + Python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm using this link as an example to uploading images:

https://gist.github.com/jdstanhope/5079277

My HTML code:

```
 <form action="/upload_image" method="post" id="form1" runat="server">
       <div class="fileButtons">
         <input type='file' id="imgInp" name="imgInput" accept="image/*"/><br><br>
         <input type='button' id='remove' value='Remove' />
        </div></form>
```

main.py:

```
class SetImage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.debug("test")
        id = str(self.request.get('id'))
        image = self.request.get('imgInput')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/upload_image', SetImage),
                               ('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

But when I add an image, nothing is being done, and the log console doesn't print:

```
logging.debug("test")
```

Comment: add enctype='multipart/form-data' to your form. Also, post doesn't appear to be doing anything other than assigning values for id and image. Use logging.info or simple print

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of uploading images to GAE is by using [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/).

Here is a quick breakdown of the doc to help you achieve this fast:

Imports:

```
import os
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
```

Serve the form HTML. this form performs the POST to GAE with the selected files data:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write("""Upload File: 
                <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
                name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")
```

Add a handler for receiving the POST data (binary content of the file). the last line in this function is to redirect the response to the location from where the file could be downloaded:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        # 'file' is file upload field in the form
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

Add handler to serve the image that you uploaded using the UploadHandler described above:

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

And finally, define the routes for the app:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                           ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                           ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler)],
                            debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue of your log statement not firing: The default log level for `dev_appserver.py` is `info`, which you can override with the `--dev_appserver_log_level` flag.

Reference the [new dev_appserver documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver#New_Development_Server).

To access uploaded files from a multipart/form-data POST request, the [webapp2 documentation states](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#files) that they're available in `request.POST`.